# Unable to Register in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Recently I was trying to develop an application where registration is required. I am trying to use Firebase for this purpose but I don't know what's going on but I am unable to register. Below is the code

```
mRegBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reg_btn);
mDisNam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_dis_name);
mLastNam = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_las_name);
mEmailid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_id);
mPasswd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_pass);
mPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_phone);
mCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_phon);
```

The above code is for the attributes that I am having in my registration screen.

```
mRegBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String display_name = mDisNam.getEditableText().toString();
        String last_name = mLastNam.getEditableText().toString();
        String email = mEmailid.getEditableText().toString();
        String password = mPasswd.getEditableText().toString();
        String p = mCode.getEditableText().toString();
        String ph = mPhone.getEditableText().toString();
        String phone = p + ph;

        registerUser(display_name, last_name, email, password, phone);
    }
});
```

The above code is for register user after clicking the register button

```
private void registerUser(String display_name, String last_name, String email, String password, String phone) {

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You Registered Successfully",Toast
                        .LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You Registered UnSuccessfully",Toast
                        .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

The code is for registration in Firebase but every time I press the register button only the unsuccessful toast pops up.

Comment: capture and upload logs in your question

Comment: Use  `getException()` to get reason

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Firebase Console > Authentication > Sign in methods. And then enable Email/Password option.

Comment: I hope your error is resolved. So accept the answer be checking the tick on left side of my answer, which can be useful for others too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support but the problem was in the TextInputLayout I was using. While assigning the id's I was assigning them to them to the TextInputEditText Instead of in TextInputLayout that's why the type cast exception was arising. I corrected it and the error vanished.